# Update on duplicate keys with delete on not updated

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The problem is:

I have got a table of columns (A, B, C) where A+B accounts for a unique key. A few records shall be updated (set is on C) and some records are new, unique A+B keys do not exist in the table. The perfect is `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but... Not updated rows (within a considered value for the A column - the same A value for all updates considered) should be deleted. The question is what is the finest way to do it, preferably a shortest query/stored procedure. I found the way around but I am looking for a more specyfic solution to the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is to have a `todelete` flag. Set it to `1` on all rows before updating, then during the update set updated rows to have `todelete=0`. Then delete any rows where `todelete` is still 1.

Comment: This is a solution what I've also taken into account, but to be frank it breaks down the logic and makes the things redundant.

Comment: Maybe you would think of some sql language mechanisms?